# Limit in DynamoDB

Tags: база-данных, node.js

Использую dynamo db. Как взять последние 10 сообщений из таблицы? Ставлю лимит, но получаю первые 10, а не последние.

```
dynamoDB
        .table(db_table_pref + table)
        .where('SN').eq(device_sn)
        .where('timestamp').le(start_date)
        .limit(10)
```

Comment: Добавьте сортировку по убыванию поля, по которому вы определяете "последнесть" записей.

Comment: @Akina так .order_by('timestamp') ?

Comment: Думаю, что если сделать именно так, то сортировка будет выполнена по возрастанию. А надо по убыванию.

Comment: Использовал .descending('timestamp'), заработало. Спасибо, напишите в ответ, я помечу как правильный

Comment: Думаю, будет правильнее, если Вы сами напишете ответ. Полностью и со ссылкой на документацию, чтобы он был реально полезен тому, кто столкнётся с аналогичной проблемой. У Вас это выйдет грамотнее - я про dynamoDB, можно сказать, только сегодня узнал, совет давал из общих соображений, и запросто могу написАть чего не то...